# method not found in `PalletId`

Tags: polkadot

I need to use this field when configuring config under runtime. The compiler can jump through ctrl, but an error is reported during the compilation process.

this is my code.

```
pub NativeTreasuryAccount: AccountId = TreasuryPalletId::get().into_account();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Did you import the trait as suggested in the error message?

`use sp_runtime::traits::AccountIdConversion;`